# 110V Voltage variation with op-amp

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, analog

I made a project with the objective of changing the supply voltage of a system (VOUT in the circuit) through a PWM signal.

The initial objective was to vary the supply voltage of a secondary circuit (bridge H) from 0V to 110V continuous.

I thought of doing this using a system with an op amp. I put an RC circuit on the amplifier input to convert the PWM signal into an analog signal. My intention was as follows: 50% duty = 55V at the output; 100% duty = 110V (approximate considering drops) at the output.

But what I have in VOUT is a pulsing signal with amplitude of 120V and RMS voltage varying (that wasn't my intention).

can anybody help me?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBe4kZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT 1:

The VOUT load will be an H-bridge. Similar to the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkavH3.png)</sup>

Comment: What is the frequency of your PWM signal? What does the voltage across C1 look like?

Comment: Is V1 110VAC or 110VDC? It is shown on the schematic as DC.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The frequency is easily changed by uc if necessary, but the tests I did were with 100kHz. The voltage at C1 seems to continue. 1.6V with 50% duty.

Comment: @VoltageSpike It's 110VDC continuous.

Comment: What does the load look like? This circuit is an oscillator.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The VOUT load will be an H-bridge.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Any suggestions on how to make the circuit stop being an oscillator and vary the constant voltage at VOUT?

Comment: Compensating it for a range of loads might be a bit challenging. I would suggest changing the design to decrease the maximum voltage gain (say of the order of 1 inclusive of the voltage divider feedback)  and take the output from a transistor emitter if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is not compensated correctly, you will  need to run a spice  AC analysis to ensure that there the overall loop has no resonance points and has a good roll-off (it should look like a low pass filter).

Try making it more of a low pass filer by making a pole in the system on the feedback loop by putting a cap in parallel with R7.

I'd run the analisys but I'm away from my machine

Comment: Even if the loop is changed will the circuit still behave like an oscillator on VOUT?

Comment: Don't know, run the analysis in spice